# FIRRemoteConfig.activateFetched() fails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I've implemented FIRRemoteConfig and added my first value in the firebase console.  However, when I try to activate the fetched values it fails and my remote value  is never available.

```
    let remote = FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    #if DEBUG
        let expiration: TimeInterval = 0
        remote.configSettings = FIRRemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
    #else
        let expiration: TimeInterval = 24*60*60
    #endif

    var map = [String:NSObject]()
    let defaults = RemoteSettings.defaults.keys
    for key in defaults.keys {
        map[key.rawValue] = defaults[key] as? NSObject
    }
    remote.setDefaults(map) // Have confirmed that map is valid here

    remote.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expiration, completionHandler: { (status, error) in
        // status always == .success, but remote.activateFetched() always returns false.
        if status == .success && remote.activateFetched() {
            print("applied remote settings")
        } else {
            print("failed to apply remote settings: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Try to call remote.activateFetched method inside the if statement...

Comment: That should not matter, but tested and it still fails.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting in the else part?

Comment: Error is `nil` because `success == .success`.  Somehow the fetch is successful, but cannot be activated.

Answer (score 11):

I figured out after a lot of trial and error. The problem is with the expiration value, set the expiration value to 0 seconds to see the immediate results put into effect!

I hope this could save a lot of time for others guys!

Answer (score 3):

Using `remote.activateFetched()` fails, but using `FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activateFetched()` is successful.  Perhaps google wants us to use `remoteConfig()` every time rather than holding onto a specific instance.

Additionally, a look at the documentation mentions that this will actually fail if the fetched settings have already been applied previously.

> Returns false if no Fetched Config was found, **or the Fetched Config was already activated**.

Answer (score 3):

As @Sunil Phani Manne mentioned, using the method with expiration value really works and forces remoteConfig to activate immediately.

```swift
    self.remoteConfig?.fetch(withExpirationDuration: 0.0, completionHandler: { (status, error) in
        let result = self.remoteConfig?.activateFetched()
        print(result)
    })
```

Comment: Just add timing to withExpirationDuration: more than 0.0, otherwise you might be blocked by Firebase